# Google contact api for android

Tags: java, android, android-contacts, google-contacts-api

I need to implement google contact api for my android app. But I did not found any reference for android so far. I have found one for java: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/

but when I use this code:

```
ContactsService myService = new ContactsService("<var>YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME</var>");
```

I get a runtime error called "exceptionInInitializerError".

I have already looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727531/google-contacts-api-on-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362227/google-contacts-data-api-on-android-not-working) but not getting specefic solution that how can I initialize a "ContactsService" object.

So can any of you kindly provide me a guideline that how can I implement the google contact api in my app?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code it may help you

```
    public void printAllContacts()throws ServiceException, IOException {

    ContactsService myService = null;
    myService = new ContactsService(accessToken);//add here your access token
    myService.setAuthSubToken(accessToken);//add here your access token
    URL feedUrl = new URL("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=5000");
    ContactFeed resultFeed = myService.getFeed(feedUrl, ContactFeed.class);
    for (int i = 0; i < resultFeed.getEntries().size(); i++) {
        ContactEntry entry = resultFeed.getEntries().get(i);
        if (entry.hasName()) {
            Name name = entry.getName();
            if (name.hasFullName()) {
                String fullNameToDisplay = name.getFullName().getValue();
                if (name.getFullName().hasYomi()) {
                    fullNameToDisplay += "("
                            + name.getFullName().getYomi() + ")";
                }
                System.out.println(fullNameToDisplay);
            }
            for (Email email : entry.getEmailAddresses()) {

                System.out.println(email.getAddress());
            }
            Link photoLink = entry.getContactPhotoLink();
            String photoLinkHref = photoLink.getHref();
            System.out.println("Photo Link:" + photoLinkHref+"\n");
        }
    }
}
```